# Cutesy Applications of Fermat's Last Theorem (or others)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Remembering that a STEP mathematics question which guided us through showing $n^3 + (n-3)^3 = (n+3)^3$ has no solutions in the integers could be sledgehammered with Fermat's Last Theorem, I wondered if there are other fun ways to apply Fermat's Last Theorem.

Another example:

**Claim** $ \sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational for all integers n > 3

**Proof** Suppose to the contrary, that $ \sqrt[n]{2} = \frac{p}{q}$ for integers p and q. Then $q^n + q^n = p^n $. A contradiction (Wiles, 95).

Any other examples? I'd be happy to see applications of other big theorems (such as the Catalan conjecture/Mihăilescu's theorem). Fermat fits naturally because of the gulf in the elementariness of the statement and the difficulty of the proof.

Comment: More generally $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$ is irrational if $a,b>0$, otherwise $p^n=(qa)^n + (qb)^n$.

Comment: I'm sure there are examples that use the classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: See a comment on circularity of this proof: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts/42519#42519

Answer (score 3):

This so called application of Fermat's great theorem was given at a Romanian olympiad. It is not suitable for such a purpose, but I'm not sure why this was accepted as a contest problem.

> Prove that if $n$ is odd, $a,b,c$ are non-zero integers and
>   $$ a^{3n}+b^{3n}+3(abc)^n=c^{3n} $$
>   then $P(a,b,c)$.

Where $P(a,b,c)$ is a statement about $a,b,c$ which can be deduced from $a=b=-c$.

Proof:
$$ (a^n)^3+(b^n)^3+(-c^n)^3-3(a^n\cdot b^n\cdot (-c^n))=0$$

and then we use
$$ x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)$$

Comment: Beni Bogosel, where is FLT used? Is it somewhere from a = b = -c to P(a,b,c)?

Comment: One of the factors given by the equation is $a^n+b^n-c^n$ which by FLT is never zero.

Comment: So how to deduce $a=b=-c$?

Comment: From the other part of the product $(a^n-b^n)^2+(b^n+c^n)^2+(a^n+c^n)^2 = 0$.